# Snakemake skips multiple of the rules with same input

Tags: snakemake

Let's say I have 3 rules with the same input, snakemake skips 2 of them and only runs one of the rules. Is there a workaround to force all 3 rules to execute, since I need all 3 of them? I could add some other files as input to the existing input, but I feel like that's somewhat cheated and probably confusing to other people looking at my code, since I declare an input that is not used at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears [target files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets-and-aggregation) were not defined. By default, snakemake executes the first rule in the snakefile.

Example:

```
rule all
   input: "a.txt", "b.png"

rule x:
   output "a.txt"
   shell: "touch {output}"

rule y:
   output "b.png"
   shell: "touch {output}"
```

It is customary to name the first rule `all` which has all the desired output files.

Comment: My bad... it was as simple as this, I just forgot to add 1 single line.